# Replacing singleton data types with a data family

Tags: haskell, dependent-type, type-families

So in my current project, I find myself doing a bunch of type-level logic with singleton types.

For example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
module TypeBools where

type family (||) (a :: Bool) (b :: Bool) :: Bool where
  'False  || 'False = 'False
  'False  || 'True  = 'True
  'True   || 'False = 'True
  'True   || 'True  = 'True

data OrProof (a :: Bool) (b :: Bool) (c :: Bool) where
  OrProof :: SBool (a || b) -> OrProof a b (a || b)

data SBool (b :: Bool) where
  SFalse  :: SBool 'False
  STrue   :: SBool 'True

class Boolean b where
  sBool :: SBool b
instance Boolean 'False where
  sBool = SFalse
instance Boolean 'True where
  sBool = STrue

orProof :: (Boolean a, Boolean b) => OrProof a b (a || b)
orProof = go sBool sBool where

  go :: SBool a -> SBool b -> OrProof a b (a || b)
  go SFalse SFalse = OrProof SFalse
  go SFalse STrue = OrProof STrue
  go STrue SFalse = OrProof STrue
  go STrue STrue = OrProof STrue
```

And this is working pretty well for me. I like not having to cart around the the 
singleton types manually, being able to summon them when necessary via typeclass 
(e.g. the `Boolean` class above), but this has led to a bunch of fairly similar 
typeclasses that exist only to reify the type as singleton data.

I thought maybe I could abstract those multiple typeclasses into a single type family,
for example replacing `SBool` and `Boolean` above with:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
-- ...
class Singleton (t :: k) where
  data Sing t
  sing :: Sing t

instance Singleton 'False where
  data Sing 'False = SFalse
  sing = SFalse

instance Singleton 'True where
  data Sing 'True = STrue
  sing = STrue

type SBool b = Sing (b :: Bool)

type Boolean b = Singleton (b :: Bool)
sBool :: Boolean b => SBool b
sBool = sing
```

But then I get pattern match errors:

```
TypeBools2.hs:42:13:
    Couldn't match type ‘b1’ with ‘'True’
      ‘b1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
           the type signature for
             go :: SBool a1 -> SBool b1 -> OrProof a1 b1 (a1 || b1)
           at TypeBools2.hs:40:9
    Expected type: SBool b1
      Actual type: Sing 'True
    Relevant bindings include
      go :: SBool a1 -> SBool b1 -> OrProof a1 b1 (a1 || b1)
        (bound at TypeBools2.hs:41:3)
    In the pattern: STrue
    In an equation for ‘go’: go SFalse STrue = OrProof STrue
    In an equation for ‘orProof’:
        orProof
          = go sBool sBool
          where
              go :: SBool a -> SBool b -> OrProof a b (a || b)
              go SFalse SFalse = OrProof SFalse
              go SFalse STrue = OrProof STrue
              go STrue SFalse = OrProof STrue
              go STrue STrue = OrProof STrue
```

I'm not sure whether there's something more I can convince the compiler
that `b1` should have kind `Bool`, or if I'm just barking up the wrong tree here.

Comment: May I ask why your `||` does not short-circuit? I'd expect better reduction with `'False || x = x; 'True || x = 'True`, for example.

Comment: You should just use [`singletons`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-2.0.1/docs/Data-Singletons.html), but if you aren't going to use it, you should see how they do it and copy it (because they do precisely what you want). In particular, you need a *non* associated data family `data family Sing (t :: k); class Singleton (t :: k) where sing :: Sing t` and `data instance Sing (b :: Bool) where ...`

Comment: dfeuer: it could. That's besides the question, though.

Comment: Also, I'm having trouble seeing what your `OrProof` and `orProof` are supposed to express. They seem a bit ... roundabout. I know that doesn't relate directly to your question.

Comment: dfeuer: this is a simplified example for the question, but it allows you to do type-level logic without worrying about the inability of GHC (pre8) to reason about injectivity by carting around the arguments.  For example, `or :: (Boolean a, Boolean b) => SBool (a || b); or = case orProof of OrProof c -> c` gives the old `NB: ‘||’ is a type function, and may not be injective` ambiguity error.

Comment: dfeuer: but I also need access to the structure of the final type, which I can't get from proxies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your requested feature and much more can be found in [`singletons`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons). It has been the  definitive template for type-level programming for quite a long time. You should either use it or copy the implementation. Anyway, I'll do here a brief showcase for a simplified `singletons` solution.

Your pattern match doesn't work because `STrue` and `SFalse` are in different data definitions, and those aren't GADT to begin with. Pattern matching only refines types when done on proper GADT-s. We need to dispatch on *kinds*, in order to be able to group together all the singleton constructors of a kind.

We can do this either with a proper kind class or a top-level data family. The latter is simpler for our purposes now, so let's do that:

```
data family Sing (x :: k)

data instance Sing (b :: Bool) where
  STrue :: Sing True
  SFalse :: Sing False
```

With `sing` we don't need kind dispatch because we only use it for getting specific lifted values, so the following works:

```
class SingI (x :: k) where
   sing :: Sing x

instance SingI True  where sing = STrue
instance SingI False where sing = SFalse
```

As to `orProof`, what we'd like to have is a singleton for the type-level `(||)`, which is most straightforwardly accomplished with the following type : `Sing b1-> Sing b2 -> Sing (b1 || b2)`. We shall name it `(%:||)`, in accordance with the hieroglyphic `singletons` naming practice.

```
type family (:||) (b1 :: Bool) (b2 :: Bool) :: Bool where
  True  :|| b = True
  False :|| b = b

(%:||) :: Sing b1 -> Sing b2 -> Sing (b1 :|| b2)
(%:||) STrue  b2 = STrue
(%:||) SFalse b2 = b2
```

`OrProof` isn't very useful, since it's just a specialized equality type along with a `SingI` constraint or a plain `Sing c`:

```
type OrProof a b c = SingI c => c :~: (a :|| b)
type OrProof' a b c = (Sing c, c :~: (a :|| b))
```

Comment: `singletons` pretty much has everything that's humanly possible with current GHC. It's not simple, so feel free to ask further questions if you have problems. I also have a number of singletons-related answers on this site which you may want to [check out](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1068232+singletons).